# How to pass a JS Object to a ASP.net Controller?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to pass a object to an IActionResult and it a list of those objects, I am using AJAX (Jquery) but when **I start to debugging the object came with null values to my controller.**

I try to change the structure of my ajax code, but I am really new into this.

This is my controller, recibes a Contact

//models

```
public class Contact
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

//HomeController

```
public JsonResult addContact(Contact _contact)
    {
        bool isThere = false;
        foreach(Contact c in this.contacts){
            if( c.phone == _contact.phone ){
                isThere = true;
            }
        }

        if(!isThere){
            this.contacts.Add(_contact);
            return Json(new { msg = "ok" });
        }
        else{
            return Json(new { msg = "exists" });
        }
    }
```

And this is my .js

```
function addContact() {
$('#addUserModal').modal("hide");
var _firstName = $('#firstName').val();
var _lastName = $('#lastName').val();
var _email = $('#email').val();
var _phone = $('#phone').val();
var _company = $('#company').val();
//let's create a objet just like our user.cs
var Contact = {
    firstName: _firstName,
    lastName: _lastName,
    email: _email,
    phone: _phone,
    company: _company
};
console.log(Contact);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utg-8',
    url: "/Home/addContact",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        '_contact': Contact
    }),

    error: function () {
        toastr.error('system Error, check your connection or re-debug your code', 'Error', {
            timeOut: 6000,
            positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'
        });
    },

    success: function (data) {
        if (data.msg === "ok") {
            toastr.success('OK, Contact added', 'ok', {
                timeOut: 6000,
                positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'
            });
            $("#addContactModal").modal("hide"); //to hide my idModal
            $("#listContactTableId").load("/Home/getContacts");
        }
        else if (data.msg === "exists") {
            toastr.error("You're trying to add a user that alreday exists", "Eye!", {
                timeOut: 6000,
                positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'
            });
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `JSON.stringify()` on your data - you're actually performing a double encoding since `$.ajax()` will encode it automatically. Just pass the data as `data: { '_contact': Contact }`.

Comment: @viviramji can you try data : $('form').serialize() ?

Answer (score 0):

``

```
  [HttpPost]public string addContact(Contact obj){ return "Success";}
```

Here firstname and lastname should be the property in your model.LIke 
public string MyName....etc. Please Try @viviramji

```js
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
var a= $("#IDforName").val();
var b=$("idLatname").val();

$.ajax({
type:"post",
url: "@Url.Action("addContact","YourControllerName")",
data:
{
firstname:a,
lastname:b
},
success: function()
{
alert("success!");
}

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="IDforName" placeholder="Enter Name" name="firstname"/>

<input type="text" id="idLatname" placeholder="Enter lastname" name="lastname"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: Hi Ricky, Bro, when I try this:  ... url: "@Url.Action("AddContact","YourControllerName")",...

 the .js doesn't find the correctly route.

Comment: Ok will you please show me how you have written your controller action method ?

Comment: Please match your action method name to your url in ajax @viviramji

Answer (score 0):

your model need just the object not a wrapper, change this

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        '_contact': Contact
    })
```

to

```
data: JSON.stringify(Contact)
```